Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API only returns requestId and totalBilledTime
Response body
I'm trying to implement the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API in unity.
The url uses "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key="+{API_KEY}
The detailed code is below.
The response request.downloadHandler.text only contains requestId and totalBilledTime.
Is there any solution?
I want to be able to get the correct response data.
Normal response body
{
results,
totalBilledTime,
speechAdaptationInf,
requestId,
}
        var jsonRequest = new SpeechToTextRequest
        {
            config = new AudioConfig { encoding = "LINEAR16", sampleRateHertz = 16000, languageCode = "ja-JP"},
            audio = new SpeechToTextInput { content = base64Audio}
        };

        var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST")
        {
            uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(jsonRequest))),
            downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()
        };
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


        await request.SendWebRequest().ToUniTask();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            var response = request.downloadHandler.text;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error: {request.error}");
        }


    [Serializable]
    private class SpeechToTextRequest
    {
        public AudioConfig config;
        public SpeechToTextInput audio;
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class AudioConfig
    {
        public string encoding = "LINEAR16";
        public int sampleRateHertz = 16000;
        public string languageCode = "ja-JP";
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class SpeechToTextInput
    {
        public string content;
    }

The AudioClip data is Base64 encoded and put into base64Audio.
The conversion to Base64 is in the following format
     string ConvertAudioClipToBase64(AudioClip clip)
    {
        float[] samples = new float[clip.samples * clip.channels];
        clip.GetData(samples, 0);


        short[] pcmData = ConvertToPCM16(samples);


        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("output.pcm", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                foreach (short sample in pcmData)
                {
                    binaryWriter.Write(sample);
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] audioData = File.ReadAllBytes("output.pcm");


        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(audioData);
        return base64String;
    }

    private short[] ConvertToPCM16(float[] samples)
    {
        short[] pcmData = new short[samples.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            pcmData[i] = (short)(Mathf.Clamp(samples[i], -1f, 1f) * short.MaxValue);
        }
        return pcmData;
    }


Can you post the actual JSON in the response text?

The AudioClip data is Base64 encoded and put into base64Audio.
Base64 is a long text, so it is difficult to attach it.

response, not request. The response is text, is it not?

The response is expected to contain text.
The actual response data looks like this (requestId is hidden):
{
"totalBilledTime": "0s",
"requestId": "0000000000000000000"
}

The expected values ​​are:
{
"results": [
{
object (SpeechRecognitionResult)
}
],
"totalBilledTime": string,
"speechAdaptationInfo": {
object (SpeechAdaptationInfo)
},
"requestId": string
}

As far as I can tell you're doing everything right and the response doesn't match the documentation. You get a success response, but only half of the documented items are in the response: you should at least get an empty result, not a completely missing one. Sorry I can't help any further, I'm interested to know the solution if you come up with one.

The response content only contains half of the items listed in the documentation.
It doesn't even return an empty result, and there's no error, so I don't know what to do.

try to put:
enableAutomaticPunctuation: true
if it doesn't work try to put some sampleRateHertz
in the config object in body

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
